# How to properly handle an all clad pan

Tags: pan

I just bought all clad's chef's pan (HA1) and their 10 piece set.

[image: Chef's pan 12']

However, I quickly find out it's very uncomfortable to hold it by gripping the U shape handle from upper side or sideway, the edge of the handle cut in to my palm. And because the pan is very heavy (for good reason), it becomes very hard to lift it up and tilt it.

I did some research and find lots of people having this complain. There are some solution like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I8l2uDhvDVQ) YouTube video, but it does not actually solve the lift and tilt problem.

I wonder what did professionals did when handling such kind of job?

Comment: Welcome! If I had to guess, I'd bet that pros pick up the pans and try them out before buying and wouldn't buy this pan if it's not comfortable to hold.

Comment: It looks like there's a helper handle on the other side to help lifting it.  But I'd recommend investing in a good leather, silicone, or thick padded pot holder, as it'll help pad the handle.  A kitchen towel can help, but dedicated pot holders tend to be a bit thicker and stiffer, which helps to spread the pressure out more.

Comment: Oh, and my understanding is that although high-end chefs (tv, personal chefs, etc) might use expensive pots & pans like this, many professionals are using relatively cheap pans or really large ones that you'd never use if just cooking for a family (of less than 12 people, at least)

Comment: Have you asked the seller for a solution? If they sell you something that does not work they should provide a solution or refund it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If impressing guests is not in order, some string and cork (possibly cut to shape) is the cheap way to improve a handle. E.g. I got tired of the all-metal tea pot handle being hot and probably in hindsight used too much string

[image: metal handle with cork and string]

Comment: That's inventive. And I don't think too much string; it's beautiful.

Comment: I like this idea, even though I'll probably put the cork on top.